# PHP: filter: calculating age from birthday, BETWEEN xx AND xx

Tags: php

After some research and little afford from myself I got this:

```
     $query .= "SELECT * FROM users WHERE birthday < SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL BETWEEN $min AND $max YEAR)";
```

Although this doesn't work.

Users birthdays are stored in: 1991-01-01 in the birthday column. I have two fields in my form, that you can enter numbers in. example, 18 and 22.

then it will show all users that has the age between 18 and 22 ( 18,19,20,21,22).

^ And that is what im trying to filter out, with the query. But ive done something wrong, and maybe you cant do BETWEEN in INTERVAL, or what is wrong?

Im getting:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BETWEEN 17 AND 21 YEAR)' at line 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But ive done something wrong, and maybe you cant do BETWEEN in INTERVAL, or what is wrong?

Exactly - `BETWEEN` is a boolean operator, which means it returns a boolean value (true or false), and `INTERVAL` wants an integer.

```
WHERE birthday
  BETWEEN SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL $max YEAR)
      AND SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL $min YEAR)
```

and a warning - you better have those variables properly escaped (with `mysql_escape_string`). [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)!

Also note that: using NOW() means that you would be including people born 17 years 23 hours ago, but excluding people born 18 years and 1 hour ago. That is not typically what we mean by "birthday" - you would better use `TODAY()` than `NOW()`.

However, with `TODAY()`, there is another issue: `BETWEEN` is inclusive; thus, between 18 and 20, you do not have 2 years, but 2 years and a day. Overcome this by splitting `BETWEEN` up and doing normal comparison (`birthday > ... AND birthday <= ...`)

Comment: +1 Good answer =) I usually fetch values from MySQL and parse them in PHP, so I'm not too good at having MySQL parse it for me.

Comment: I don't like parsing dates - whenever I'm fetching dates, I pretty much always fetch `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(field)`, and store `FROM_UNIXTIME(time)`...

Comment: Hello. Nice solutions. could you show example with using TODAY(), as I want to exclude less people possible.

Comment: `WHERE birthday >= SUBDATE(TODAY(), INTERVAL $max YEAR) AND birthday < SUBDATE(TODAY(), INTERVAL $min YEAR)`, where `$min` is one less than what the user entered; (e.g., for 18 and 22, `$max` is 22, `$min` is 17)

Comment: Im getting FUNCTION .TODAY does not exist

Answer (score 0):

The SQL line `BETWEEN` only takes two parameters after it. You would say `BETWEEN $min AND $max`, not `BETWEEN $min AND $max YEAR`.

If you stored the date as a MySQL DATE rather than as an INT or a String, there are MySQL functions that can interpret just parts of the date using `MONTH(date)`, `YEAR(date)`, etc.

Try reading through [this MySQL reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) and see if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an option, I'd say cut the clutter and modify the mysql column or create a column that saves the date of birth as an integer. For example, 1991-12-01 as you have it now would be 19911201. That way you could just use something like:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE birthday >= min AND birthday <= max
```

By the way: Avoid using * in the select query if possible.